# Unable to ODBC connect to Teradata via PHP

Tags: php, odbc, teradata

Windows' (7) ODBC administrator is configured with my username and password. I am having trouble connecting to my Teradata DB using ODBC and php. I have no trouble connecting with Python by simply using the connection string "DSN=Teradata"

```
import pypyodbc
conn = pypyodbc.connect('DSN=Teradata')
```

or R,

```
require(RODBC)
odbcConnect('Teradata')
```

But the following code

```
<?php
  $conn = odbc_connect('DSN=Teradata');
  $query = odbc_exec($conn, "select top 10 * from pretendTable");
  while(odbc_fetch_row($query)) {
    odbc_result($query, 1);
  }
  echo "END";
?>
```

only outputs "END". Any ideas?

**EDIT**

and also, VBA

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

cn.Open "Teradata"
rs.Open "Select top 10 * from pretendTable", cn
```

php is the only one that is not cooperating

**EDIT 2**

Somewhat repaired.

I have two installs of php on my computer. One was installed by wamp, the other using the php.net binary executable. It is the latter that is not working. This leads me to believe that the ODBC package/functionality does not come installed by default. However, I'll defer to the hive...

The former works with `$conn = odbc_connect("Teradata","pretendUsername","pretendPassword");`

Comment: Check the value of $conn after you call `odbc_connect()`.  And also check $query after calling `odbc_exec()`.  Your line: `odbc_connect('DSN=Teradata')`  might need to be `odbc_connect("DSN=Teradata")`

Comment: It's NULL. Both with/out "DSN=". Should I be loading a package?

Comment: Look at the edit in my last comment.  Should you be using `"` instead of `'`?

Comment: Double quotes instead of singles didn't do it.

Comment: Did it at least result in non-null variables?

Comment: @ryyker Obviously you ignore the difference between double and single quotes in PHP. It's all about variable expansion and backslashes. The string `DSN=Teradata` obviously does not contain either \ nor `$`.

Comment: Yeah, obvious, I guess.